# Retrieving Hash Code for Site Collection

Tags: development, site

$sc =Get-SPSiteAdministration -identity siteurl

$sc | GetHashCode

It doesnt work.. Is there any other implementation of the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Hash Code of the site collection using following:

```
$s = Get-SPSite -Identity siteurl
$s.GetHashCode()
```

Comment: Tick mark the answer to close the question @SuhaylBhat